# Is there any sql-query to check the value is exist or not in db table

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database table have this value,i have to check this email value 'abc@gmail.com' is exist in the database or not.

```
abc@gmail.com
edf@dfg.com
xyz@abcinfo.com
12345@fdfg.com
```

If 'abc@gmail.com' value is exist in the database table, output is true else false, so how to write the query for this to achieve?

thanks 
Kumar

Comment: thanks for comments i will improve my questions and how to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something as simple as
`select CASE WHEN count(1) > 0 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END from table where email = 'abc@gmail.com'`

But you should give some more information for a beater answer.

Comment: thanks this is actually i expect.

Answer (score 2):

you can write query like

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) >0, TRUE,FALSE)as response FROM <tablename> WHERE emailid='edf@dfg.com';
```

Comment: thanks this code is improve my programming knowledge and is useful too...

Comment: @developerCK, Thanks for this post, This piece I want.

Comment: hi this is only show 1 only if mutli time the mail id exist in the table. So to get the no. of time the mail id exist in table

Comment: SELECT IF(COUNT(*) >0, TRUE,FALSE)as response, count(*) as nooftimes FROM <tablename> WHERE emailid='edf@dfg.com', it is * b/w count parenthesis;

Answer (score 1):

```
select exists(
   SELECT 1 FROM <tableName> WHERE email LIKE 'abc@gmail.com'
)
```