# java jdbc check whether a value exist in a database table

Tags: java, jdbc

I got part of my answer from
[Is there any sql-query to check the value is exist or not in db table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977438/is-there-any-sql-query-to-check-the-value-is-exist-or-not-in-db-table)

In the comment of Paraíso

But I can't copy the return value to a boolean variable.
It gives an error as

```
SEVERE: null<br>
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation at current cursor position.
```

My code:

```
String sel="select CASE WHEN count(1) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END from ledgerslist where ledger = 'dera'";
PreparedStatement stc=conn.prepareStatement(sel);
ResultSet rsk=stc.executeQuery(); 
Boolean cc=false; 
cc=rsk.getBoolean(1); 
conn.close(); 
System.out.println(cc);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `'` characters so you get Boolean value instead of a string:

```
select CASE WHEN count(1) > 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END from table where email = 'abc@gmail.com'
```

See [MySQL's boolean literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/boolean-literals.html)

> The constants TRUE and FALSE evaluate to 1 and 0, respectively. The constant names can be written in any lettercase.

Comment: it shows same error. My code is given here                                                      
String sel="select CASE WHEN count(1) > 0 THEN true ELSE false END from ledgerslist where ledger = 'dera'";
            
            PreparedStatement stc=conn.prepareStatement(sel);
           
            ResultSet rsk=stc.executeQuery();
             Boolean cc=false;
          
                    cc=rsk.getBoolean(1);
                    conn.close();
            
                System.out.println(cc);

Comment: @ArunBR Add `if (rsk.next()) {` before `getBoolean`

Comment: I used this method and it works fine.

Comment: @ArunBR if it helped you can accept the answer

Comment: This answer doesn't address the problem of _"java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation at current cursor position._"